# How do I get a .cer and private key

Tags: certificate

We need a .cer so a 3rd party can validate our requests and responses. How do I go about getting one?

Comment: Do you need one signed by a certificate authority, or do you just need a self-signed one? You can generate a .cer file with makecert.exe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=VS.100).aspx) or OpenSSL. If you need a signed one, you have to look at a certificate authority like Thawte, GeoTrust, Verisign.

Comment: @birryree this should definetely go as an asnwer, because it is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is way too broad to be answered within StackOverflow.

If the other party has it's own requirements regarding what certificates must be used, then you need to follow that requirements. Also it's possible that this party issues certificates itself, in which case they will give you one.

If you are developing both sides of the communication, you can generate your own self-signed certificates and validate them.

Finally, if the other party has predefined trusted certificates or uses Windows trusted certificates, then you can use one of trusted / accepted CAs to get the certificate.

In general it's strongly recommended that you read a book or two about certificate basics - how they work and how they are used. For introductory material I can offer you the [articles in our knowledgebase](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/articles/65-184.php), they cover certificate basics and use of certificates for authentication.

Comment: "Your question is way too broad to be answered within StackOverflow." disagree. perfectly valid.

Comment: Valid but too broad. We have an article about use of certificates for authenticating in client-server environments, and I can write a book on this topic as well. Guess StackOverflow doesn't let 5- or 150-page answers :)